# How init() works internally when used in C++

Tags: c++, linux, init

Init() is the initial or we can say a daemon process being called up on Bootup runs till shutdown if we won't kill it. So, this a Linux based definition. I have doubt whether the same definition is applicable in C++ environment. 
Help Appreciated.

Comment: `init()` is nothing more than six characters that look like a function call. Which init are you talking about, that is relevant to a C++ environment?

Comment: What do you mean by "applicable"?

Comment: give what ever meaning to init() as you wish in C++, but really init() functions serve to confuse people. Use sparingly.

Answer (score 3):

There is a **process** named [init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) on many<sup>1</sup>—but not all—Linux systems. It is the very first process launched by the kernel and is the parent or ancestor of all processes. init has PID 1.

This process has nothing to do with any **function** you might create named `init()`, in the same way that a function named `bash()` has no relation to the shell `/bin/bash`. Do not conflate process names with function names. One has no connection to the other.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I say *many* Linux systems because init has been replaced by [systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) in most modern Linux distros. It looks like init will eventually become a historical relic.</sup>